# When saving Ai file as Jpeg it gets blurry

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, resolution, blur

When I save my .ai file as Jpeg by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S and it gets blurry. No matter how high or low I set in presets. Why? Help!!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your canvass settings are in high resolution which means 100-300ppi (pixels per inch)

[image]

when saving as jpeg export it. Try to see the saving details. when your using shortcuts it will give default results often times it is set to minimum.

[image]

Here are the saving settings.[image]

[image]

72ppi is good when you want the file size to be low but it affects the sharpness of the layout. If you want to make it in high resolution, sacrifice the file size saving. 100-300ppi is considered best